# Nav positioning off on device rotation

Tags: html, css, iphone

My site's nav bar width and position get messed up when rotating mobile devices. The behavior can't be replicated by simulating device rotation in Chrome. Any ideas as to what is making the container div width and positioning be off after rotation?

http://phwinemerchant.com

Screenshots:

**IDEAL BEHAVIOR**

iPhone 6 Portait (Chrome simulation): https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2VYQ.png

iPhone 6 Landscape (Chrome Simulation): https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xf0x.png

**ACTUAL BEHAVIOR**

iPhone 6 Portait (on device): https://i.stack.imgur.com/03tvz.jpg

iPhone 6 Landscape (on device):https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYjGe.jpg

Thanks!!

Comment: Post some code for us to work with

Comment: I posted the link to the page, as I'm not sure where the conflict lies and don't know what part of the code would be helpful to post.

Comment: Post the code to your navigation, CSS preferably. I tried it on my iPhone 5s, navigation looked fine in portrait, turned landscape and it was off centre, then I went back to portrait (after landscape) and it was off centre despite looking fine before initially going landscape

Comment: Yes, those are the issues I am trying to correct.